# calculate each row total price as the quantity increase or decrese in shoping cart. (quantity * price)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to calculate each item total price as the quantity increases or decreases but, when I increase the quantity the price of first row is placed in all other rows.

**Here is Html code**

```
<form method="post" action="n/GetPostData.php">
  <?php 
    $total=0; $all_cart_products=$shoping_cart->allShopingcartValue($id); 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_cart_products)) { ?>
  <!-- Shopin Cart -->
  <tr class="cart_item">
    <td class="product-remove">
      <a id="" class="remove"  href="<?php echo $row['shoping_cart_id']; ?>">×</a>
    </td>
    <input id="p_id" type="hidden" name="shoping_cart_id" value="<?php echo $row['shoping_cart_id'] ?>">
    <td class="product-thumbnail">
      <a href="single-product.html"><img width="180" height="180" src="assets/images/products/2.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <!-- <input type="hidden" name="image" value=""> -->
    </td>
    <td data-title="Product" class="product-name">
      <a href="single-product.html"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">
    </td>
    <td data-title="Price" class="product-price">
      <span class="amount">$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></span>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_price[]" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" class="p_price">
    </td>
    <td data-title="Quantity" class="product-quantity">
      <input type="number" name="product_quantity[]" class="input-text qty text p_quantity" title="Qty" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" max="29" min="0" step="1">
    </td>
    <td data-title="Total" class="product-subtotal">
      <span class="amount p_total_s">$<?php echo $row['total']; ?></span>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_total[]" value="<?php echo $row['total']; ?>" class="p_total">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="actions" colspan="6">
      <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" name="update_cart" class="button">
      <span></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
</form>
```

**Here is javascript jquery code**

```
$('.p_quantity').change(function() {
    var price = $('.p_price').val();
    var quantity = $('.p_quantity').val();
    $('.p_total').text(price * quantity);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the other elements *relative* to your input

When you use `$(".p_price")` it finds all of the elements with `class=p_price`.

When you use `.val()` on the collection it gives you the value of the first.
When you use `.text()` on the collection, it sets the text in each of the elements.

So `$(".p_total").text($(".p_price").val())` will set all of the p_totals to the value of the first p_price.  (and extrapolate to quantity)

By using `$(this).closest(".cart_item")` you find the "closest parent" that is a `.cart_item`.

Then using `cartitem.find(".p_price")` (etc) you get the p_price that's within the same cart_item as the p_quantity that triggers the event.

Giving:

```
$('.p_quantity').change(function() {
    var cartitem = $(this).closest(".cart_item");
    var price = cartitem.find('.p_price').val();
    //var quantity = cartitem.find('.p_quantity').val();
    var quantity = $(this).val();  // same as above, no need to re-find this
    cartitem.find('.p_total').text(price * quantity);
});
```

The last row should probably be:

```
    cartitem.find('.p_total_s').text(price * quantity);
    cartitem.find('.p_total').val(price * quantity);
```

as p_total is a hidden input, so should use `.val()`

Comment: can you explain this a little?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line $('.p_total').text(price * quantity); with:

```
$('.p_total').val(price * quantity);
```

Use val instead of text.

Comment: any explanation ?

Comment: OPs main issue is "*when I increase the quantity the price of first row is placed in all other rows*" - which this won't fix.  But yes, you should be using `.val()` for a hidden input (I've added a comment for this to my answer so as not to change this one).